# Using Angular, Typescript array appears empty in some situations, not in others

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wading into the Angular and Typescript pools and have been putting together a web app that I want as a way of getting acquainted with them.

Most of my issues I've managed to solve, but this one has me stumped.

In my class, I have an array:

```
export class HomeComponent {
    public user: User | undefined;
    public feedGroups: RSSFeedGroupProxy[] | undefined;
```

I load it with data and all is well.

In my HTML (and this isn't how I plan on having it laid out, it's just to demonstrate my issue), I have:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="feedGroups">
    <h2>{{ feedGroups[0].Name }}</h2>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div ng-for="let feedGroup of feedGroups; let i = index">
            <h3>{{i}} - {{ feedGroup ? feedGroup.Name : 'None' }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div shows and my `<h2>` tag gives me "News", which is the name of the first group.

But in my `<h3>` tags, I get: " - None"

I added the `i` just to see if there was an index. I also tried `ng-repeat` and got the same results.

I'm stumped. I'm sure it's something simple and stupid.

Thanks.

Comment: Your post is confusing. It looks like you have a mix of Angular (2+) with `ngIf` and AngularJS (1.x) with `ng-repeat`, and `ng-for`(?).  What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: @R.Richards I'm using  4.2.5. I guess I don't really get the distinction. Is AngularJS something different or is it an older version? How do I distinguish the two?

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it working.

Comment: @Pete Glad you got it working. Yes, Angular (what your using) and AngularJS are different; AngularJS being an older version that isn't really compatible with the newer. Good luck with your app!